# Why is the "Four Author Theory" of the Pentateuch so popular?

Tags: authorship, torah

Deuteronomy 31:9

**9 Then Moses wrote this Torah, and gave it to the priests, the descendants of Levi, who carried the ark of the covenant of the Lord, and to all the elders of Israel.**

Deuteronomy 31:24

**24 And it was, when Moses finished writing the words of this Torah in a scroll, until their very completion,**

I think the Bible - whether it be the Septuagint, the Masoretic text, or the Hebrew scroll - is very clear on who wrote the Five Books, the "Torah,", so why has history tried so very hard to refute it?

Comment: In its strictest sense, "Torah" refers to the Pentateuch. However (as a Jewish-to-Catholic convert), colloquially, "Torah", translated as "teachings," refers to the body of knowledge that also incorporates Psalms and Prophets, as well as their major commentaries - Mishnah, oral tradition, and the Midrash. Other Writings, parts of the Hebrew canon, such as Kings, Chronicles, Esther, Job, etc., would be ambiguous as to whether, colloquially, to refer to as Torah. In my case, and in Deuteronomy 31:9, I'm referring strictly to the written Pentateuch.

Comment: Thanks. Done. Intetestingly, *Torah* as the same in Hebrew as its transliteration, also as used in several Psalms of David.

Comment: Deuteronomy 31:9 doesn't refer to the whole Pentateuch.  Repeatedly stating that it does doesn't make it so.

Comment: Masoretic, yes. Not-so-smartphone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark Edward noted in the comments, the strict "four author theory" (better known as the [Documentary hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentary_hypothesis)) as proposed by Wellhausen and others is not really ascribed to any more nowadays. However, the main point contra the traditional view that Moses wrote the Pentateuch, namely that it is rather a heavily redacted collection of texts written in different times and contexts by different (groups of) people, remains. What is debated is to what extent different sources are true authors and to what extent they are collectors or editors. More modern approaches are the [Supplementary hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplementary_hypothesis), where authors added fragments to an already existing core body, and the Fragmentary hypothesis, where the Pentateuch is a collection of small fragments without core body. The Documentary hypothesis distinguishes itself by claiming a number of core bodies (originally four, but modifications suggest more or less) without or with only few fragmentary additions.

The advantages of these models over the traditional view that Moses wrote the first five books are many. Below is a (non-exhaustive) list of examples from different perspectives.

I can understand your initial shock and disagreement. Yes, it is possible to 'fix' these problems and argue for Moses's authorship, but it requires a lot of special pleading. It is simply not in line with decades and centuries of Biblical, cultural-historical and linguistic research.

- The tetragrammaton YHWH is revealed in Ex 3, but already used before, e.g. in Gen 2:4.
- More generally, reading the text (especially in the original Hebrew), there are distinct styles of writing. A common example is the distinction between the supposed Yahwist and Elohist source. The first uses the name YHWH, and has a very anthropological God, who is close to human beings and interacts with them (walks in the garden in Gen 2–3, visits Abraham and eats with him, etc.). The second uses the term Elohim, meaning "God", and has a more distant, cosmological God. For instance the first creation story in Gen 1 is from this source.

  I should also mention Ex 15, which is written in rather late Hebrew. It is most likely that this text is based on a long oral tradition (like many other texts in these books). But this requires that the Exodus story around Ex 15 is younger Hebrew, and hence must have been written long after the exile.
- Besides different styles of writing, it also seems that different sources have different emphases. For example, it is the hypothesis that the priestly source, P, added passages where the importance of rituals and the Levites is emphasised.
- Then there is the point of conflicting stories. It is well known that there are incompatibilities in the Bible. Mankind is created in Gen 1:26 and again in Gen 2:7. This is best explained by these being two separate stories. This is also confirmed by relationships between these stories and other, older epics from the Ancient Near East, such as Enuma Elish and the Gilgamesh epic.
- Next to conflicting stories there are also duplicate or repeated stories. In Gen 12, 20 and 26 we read of Abram, Abraham and Isaac protecting their wife and themselves by letting her to say she is their sister. This is not so much an argument for different sources, but unless we are to believe that more or less the same thing happened thrice, we can better explain this with a literary argument:

  > Genesis’ second clear literary strategy, in fact, is
  >   the intertwining among its component sections. It
  >   repeats and varies shared motifs in a way that
  >   mutually illuminates the message of each cycle.
  >   […] Readers might miss obscure parallels, but they
  >   cannot fail to notice explicit cross-references that
  >   call attention to the continuity between the cycles.
  >   […] Isaac’s story in Genesis 26, for example, does
  >   not just parallel Abraham’s story – it actually re-
  >   fers back to that story (26:1, 3-5, 15, 18, 24).

  (from *Eschatology in Genesis.* Jonathan Huddleston,
  Mohr Siebeck, Tübingen (Duitsland), 2012, p. 100)
- Moses dies at the end of the Pentateuch. Either this is prophetic, or he did not write it himself. Also the two passages you quoted in your answer are difficult to understand if Moses actually wrote them. Was the first one part of the torah that Moses gave to the elders or not.

Comment: Nice statement of the theory. I think it is fair to say it also demands a belief a person must always use the same style and language, which is obviously refuted by many ancient and modern writers.

Comment: @RevelationLad true. That is exactly the criticism of Young, Rezetko and Ehrensvärd on using linguistic methods to date (other) texts as early or late Hebrew. For the Pentateuch, it's not just style, but also theology (perhaps that should be mentioned in the answer as well). It is possible, but less conceivable, that one author would present both an anthropological and a cosmological deity. Or see e.g. the obsession of P with rituals and ancestry. Those are ideas and emphases that speak from the text that are less easily suppressed by an author. Still, you have a point there.

Comment: I gave the answer a thankful +1, but I wonder if among the scholars was a Jewish person speaking Hebrew as their first language. The Pentateuch has 7 names for God; *Yehovah* being the most common, with *Ehloheem* being second and scattered throughout the Five Books. I personally see the language discrepancies, at least compared to the Psalms 200 years later, as minimal throughout the Pentateuch, but there are quite a few jarring starts and stops - especially from a Torah scroll which has no verse, chapter, or book demarcations.

Comment: @StuW Exactly. Man cannot completely describe God yet when a writer uses a different expression for God, modern scholars conclude there must be a different writer. God forbid one man knows God is more than one way!

Comment: It must be noted, however, that the JEDP model has been rapidly falling out of favor the last decade or two, because it's far too 'neat and clean' an explanation: four complete sources, written one after the other, simply weaved together. There are newer models that build on JEDP (such as the Supplementary and Fragmentary Hypotheses), but allow for the naturally messy process that would come from multiple authors and multiple editors working across multiple centuries.

Comment: @MarkEdward thanks, I incorporated that into the answer.

Comment: @RevelationLad I also added another bullet point about different emphases of sources next to different styles.

Comment: @StuW using different names, sure. And *after* the revelation of the Tetragrammaton, it becomes much more difficult to distinguish sources using the YHWH/Elohim difference, as the terms get mixed more often. However, reading the text of Ex 3 it is just really, really odd (to avoid "logical impossibility") that Abraham could call God already by that name. That cannot be explained just by different styles or theological approaches, you need to somehow explain what happened there.

Comment: Are those really the arguments against the authorship of Moses? It sounds more like those scholars don't understand the scripture and therefore make ridiculous claims. It's very easy to refute each of those claims.

Comment: This is science. I don't know what you're thinking of, but truly prophetic writing or divine dictation are not acceptable explanations in that context.

Answer (score 0):

The Torah referred to in Deuteronomy 31 is not the entire Pentateuch.

This is obviously the case in Deuteronomy 34:5-10, which chronicles Moses' death and eulogy.  It is also clearly the case in Deuteronomy 31:9, since the verse refers to something that had already been given to the priests and carried in the Ark in the past.

"Torah" can mean "law", "instruction", and "teaching".  Most likely, the "law" that Deuteronomy 31 refers to are the commandments that were imparted directly by the Lord in the Book of Leviticus.  Deuteronomy 31-34 is an appendix to a long discourse given this time by Moses, not God.  In this sense, Deuteronomy is a sort of "second" law (or Torah): the name "Deuteronomy" comes from the title of the book in the Septuagint - ΔΕΥΤΕΡΟΝΟΜΙΟΝ (*Deuteronomion*), which literally means something like "book of the second law". The Hebrew name for Deuteronomy is "Devarim" - Hebrew for "words", taken from the first verse of the book:  *These be the words which Moses spake unto all Israel ...*

Comment: From a Jewish perspective, Moses pre-humously wrote the last 8 verses of Deuteronomy with God as his muse. The Hebrew Pentateuch contains no vowels, punctuation, or verse-chapter-book notations.

Comment: From which Jewish perspective?  I'm not aware of any Jewish scholar that believes this.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the punctuation issue.  I don't see how it is relevant.

Comment: @user33515: Being unaware of something is not the same as that certain something being non-existent. Many (but not all) pious Jews do indeed believe, following the [Talmud](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/t07/t0705.htm) (p. 45), that Moses *weepingly* penned down the *prophecy* concerning his own departure, recorded at the end of Deuteronomy. Others, however, say that the last eight verses more properly belong to Joshua (as also mentioned in the previous link).