# I am seeking examples of "interludes" (an abrupt change of tone and content which breaks the flow of the surrounding passages) in the Bible ala Job 28

Tags: job, wisdom-literature

Job 28 is often considered to be an interlude because there is an abrupt change of tone and content which breaks the flow of the surrounding passages (the dialogues between Job and his friends).

Are there examples of interludes in the other biblical books or aNE literatures?

(the closer the example in time and genre to Job the better)

By the way, just to clarify, by interlude I don't necessarily mean some later insertion by an editor or another author using another source. It might be that, but it also might be original.

**Updated 04-05-2018**

I see some are concerned that Job 28 is not an interlude, or an interlude is not possible to define at all. This is a fair concern, and I acknowledge that.
The reason I call Job 28 an interlude is that, if you go by NRSV, they have added a section heading with the word 'interlude' to Job 28. So at least the NRSV translation committee thinks that is an interlude. So in similar spirit, I am just looking for examples of similar text.

Comment: It would be useful to know what you need these passages for, to know what kind of passages would be relevant. I gave two kinds of passages in my answers. But for instance Proverbs, which is believed to be a compilation of several other ANE proverb collections, may be relevant as well depending on your context.

Comment: Job 24 likewise has no obvious introduction that identifies its author; should this also be labeled an 'interlude'? Job 28 is contextually related to Job(cmp. 27:16-17/28:1, 12:22/28:3, 14:11/28:4, 9:5-6,12:15,14:18/28:5;9, 12:15,26:8;10/28:11).

Comment: @user40520 that Job 28 comes from a different source *is* commonly accepted, see e.g. Greenstein, 2003, 'The poem on wisdom in Job 28 in its conceptual and literary contexts' in Van Wolde (ed), *Job 28: Cognition in Context*.

Comment: I have never noticed any kind of hiatus in the passage Job 26-31 that would indicate the 28th as being an interlude. I am surprised that anyone thinks it to be so.

Comment: Voted to close for two reasons. The OT at least, is not a literary narrative whose authors had any use for the devices of "literature" such as interludes. The texts are too brief, polemic and fragmented for this. Even the closest example, the cycle of Judah and Tamar in Genesis 38, is not a true interlude. It is more like the post facto placement of a fragment of tradition into a larger context. Secondly, the transcription, redaction, and copyist histories of the current MT texts are so complex as to obliterate any extended literary device that might have required more than a couple of verses.

Comment: @Abu Munir Ibn Ibrahim please see my update in the question.

Answer (score 5):

This is by no means an exhaustive collection, but here are some examples. The first set of examples are from Archaic Biblical Hebrew, they are fairly well distinguishable and do not appear to have been modified a lot. The second set of examples is from books with a complex redaction history. Here, it is usually much more difficult to distinguish sections precisely, and it is typically uncertain to what extent the transmitted version reflects the originals.

Archaic Biblical Hebrew is transmitted in the Hebrew Bible in a small number of poetic passages. These passages are integrated into later prose tales. For instance, Judges 4 and 5 tell more or less the same story, but in a completely different genre. An overview is given by Gianto, 2016, 'Archaic Biblical Hebrew' in Garr and Fassberg (eds), *A Handbook of Biblical Hebrew*, vol. 1 (p. 20):

> The Divine Warrior and His
>   acts are exalted in Exod 15:1–18 (the Song of the Sea); Num 23:7–10,
>   23:18–24, 24:3–9, 24:16–19 (the Oracles of Balaam); Deut 32:1–43 (the
>   Song of Moses); Habakkuk 3; and Psalm 68. The tradition about a common
>   patriarch is reflected in Genesis 49 (the Blessing of Jacob). In the same
>   way, the tradition about Moses as leader is preserved in Deut 33:1–29 (the
>   Blessing of Moses). Judg 5:1–30 (the Song of Deborah) represents collec-
>   tive memories about ancient heroines. 1 Sam 2:1–10 (the Song of Hannah)
>   and 2 Sam 22:2–51 // Psalm 18 (David’s Thanksgiving Psalm) also belong
>   to the corpus of ABH.

As you may know, several books have undergone a complex redaction history. It is hard to distinguish the different authors of the Pentateuch precisely, but it is widely believed (among biblical scholars, at least) that it is the product of many hands (see [Why is the "Four Author Theory" of the Pentateuch so popular?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/31418/2672) for a recent question on the topic, though there may be better ones). Another example is Isaiah. This book falls apart in three parts, all of which have a complex history themselves. See the diagrams in the appendix of Berges, 2012, *The Book of Isaiah: Its Composition and Final Form* (or in German, 1998: *Das Buch Jesaja: Komposition und Endgestalt*).

Answer (score 2):

In prophetic or poetic books (such as Job), there are often interludes that are difficult to separate clearly from the surrounding text, and determining what constitutes an "interlude" isn't very clear, especially in Job where there are long poetic excursuses), but here are a few candidates:

Isaiah 42:10-12 looks like a short psalm in the middle of a prophetic section (translations from NIV):

> Sing to the Lord a new song,
>       his praise from the ends of the earth,
>   you who go down to the sea, and all that is in it,
>       you islands, and all who live in them.
>   Let the wilderness and its towns raise their voices;
>       let the settlements where Kedar lives rejoice.
>   Let the people of Sela sing for joy;
>       let them shout from the mountaintops.
>   Let them give glory to the Lord
>       and proclaim his praise in the islands.

Compare the opening of Psalm 96 (also 98) which seems to be based on (or the basis for) the passage in Isaiah:

> Sing to the Lord a new song;
>       sing to the Lord, all the earth.
>   Sing to the Lord, praise his name;
>       proclaim his salvation day after day.
>   Declare his glory among the nations,
>       his marvelous deeds among all peoples.

The latter portion of Isaiah also contains so-called "servant songs" (e.g. 42:1-4, 52:13-53:12), but I would not consider them interludes since they don't seem to stand out from their context any more than most of the topics.

Amos contains a few short hymns that read more like interludes than continuations of his prophecy, all ending with "the Lord (God Almighty) is his name":

> He who forms the mountains,
>       who creates the wind,
>       and who reveals his thoughts to mankind,
>   who turns dawn to darkness,
>       and treads on the heights of the earth—
>       the Lord God Almighty is his name. (4:13)
>
> The Lord, the Lord Almighty—
>   he touches the earth and it melts,
>       and all who live in it mourn;
>   the whole land rises like the Nile,
>       then sinks like the river of Egypt;
>   he builds his lofty palace in the heavens
>       and sets its foundation on the earth;
>   he calls for the waters of the sea
>       and pours them out over the face of the land—
>       the Lord is his name. (9:5-6)

However, in 5:8, a similar hymn is integrated with the rest of the text (note how it continues *after* "the Lord is his name"; I used the NRSV translation for 5:9 because it preserves the style of "who..." at the beginning of this line as the Hebrew text does):

> He who made the Pleiades and Orion,
>       who turns midnight into dawn
>       and darkens day into night,
>   who calls for the waters of the sea
>       and pours them out over the face of the land—
>       the Lord is his name.
>   Who makes destruction flash out against the strong,
>       so that destruction comes upon the fortress.

Jeremiah (31:35-36) also uses the same form (imitated also in Isaiah 51:15) which is integrated into the middle of a prose narrative:

> This is what the Lord says,
>   he who appoints the sun
>       to shine by day,
>   who decrees the moon and stars
>       to shine by night,
>   who stirs up the sea
>       so that its waves roar—
>       the Lord Almighty is his name:
>
> “Only if these decrees vanish from my sight,”
>       declares the Lord,
>   “will Israel ever cease
>       being a nation before me.”

The laments of Amos 4:2 and Jeremiah 9:19,21,22 are also introduced explicitly as laments to be taught. The fact that they are introduced means that they are of course not "interludes," but they seem to have a similar function to some of the above verses that seem out of place which interrupt the text without introduction.

These are some examples of short "interludes" that were nearly certainly inserted by the author of the text for some purpose. None of them are as long as Job 28, but they are all short interruptions that might be able to shed light on the function or genre of the chapter in Job.